# Problems in throttle function in js

Tags: throttling

below 'throttle' code works good. But my question is that why we are using 'this' keyword in throttle function.
what is it actually?
please describe it.
thank you very much

```
    $("document").ready(function(){
    $("input").keypress(throttle(function(e){
      $(".div1").html($("#ip").val());
    },1000))

  function throttle(fn,dly){
    var timer=null;
    return function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer=setTimeout(function(){
        fn.apply(this,arguments);
      },dly);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fn` is a function. You can call the function in the standard way - `fn()` or you can call the `call` method or `apply` method on it.

When calling `call` or `apply` you have the option with the first argument to set the scope the function can be called in. The scope can also be set to `null` for no scope.